# Page Footer is not showing on bottom of the page

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using *JasperReports* to rendering my reports. My report design have *subreport* on *Detail* band continue with *Page Footer*. I am not sure that the *Detail* band size is not measurable because of the fetched details from the database is sometimes getting long. So, the *Page Footer* band details are adapt with bottom of the *Detail* band and It's not showing bottom of the every page. I need the *Page Footer* details are showing only bottom of the page. There is any option to do that?

I am using *JasperReports version 3.0*. Thanks in Advance.

I am afraid that, I am not well in English..

Comment: Try to put the subreport in summary band and can you post your JRXML file?

Comment: You do not need to make a large detail band. You should make a text field in detail band and make sure that its "stretchWithOverflow" field is checked. that text filed can hold the large data.